# XSLT - for each loop based on sorting

Tags: xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:CommissionEvents xmlns="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes" xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager">
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121897883089643</Serial>
            </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121903131477120</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">013035513513201221389170110454</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)">00003551350000000907</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
            <NumberList>
              <Serial barcodeContent="(00)103551350000000645" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="1" format="AI(00)">00103551350000000645</Serial>
            </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is something like the below. I tried for each loop grouping based on @filterValue and @format. Could someone help me achieving this using xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0

```
<ns2:CommissionEvents>              
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
            <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)103551350000000645" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="1" format="AI(00)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. If you can't make it work, post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: P.S. You say you want to group "based on @filterValue and @format" - but your last group has different filterValues.

Comment: P.P.S For a question about grouping, the chosen title is counterproductive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.  I'm seeing four different groups in the output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ns1="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes"
  xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/ns2:CommissionEvents" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ns2:CommissionEvent/ns1:NumberList/ns1:Serial" 
                          group-by="concat(@filterValue, '##', @format)" >
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
          <ns1:NumberList>
            <ns1:Serial>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </ns1:Serial>
          </ns1:NumberList>          
        </ns2:CommissionEvent>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with output (giving explicit prefix `ns1` whereas was implicit in the input)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:CommissionEvents xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager" xmlns="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
   <ns2:CommissionEvent>
      <ns1:NumberList xmlns:ns1="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
         <ns1:Serial>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121897883089643</Serial>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121903131477120</Serial>
         </ns1:Serial>
      </ns1:NumberList>
   </ns2:CommissionEvent>
   <ns2:CommissionEvent>
      <ns1:NumberList xmlns:ns1="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
         <ns1:Serial>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">013035513513201221389170110454</Serial>
         </ns1:Serial>
      </ns1:NumberList>
   </ns2:CommissionEvent>
   <ns2:CommissionEvent>
      <ns1:NumberList xmlns:ns1="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
         <ns1:Serial>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)">00003551350000000907</Serial>
         </ns1:Serial>
      </ns1:NumberList>
   </ns2:CommissionEvent>
   <ns2:CommissionEvent>
      <ns1:NumberList xmlns:ns1="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
         <ns1:Serial>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(00)103551350000000645" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="1" format="AI(00)">00103551350000000645</Serial>
         </ns1:Serial>
      </ns1:NumberList>
   </ns2:CommissionEvent>
</ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

Comment: The expectation is of three output <CommissionEvent> not four. The last 2 <CommissionEvent> should combine in one <CommissionEvent>. E.g. (00)003551350000000907 and (00)103551350000000645 should output in combination

Could you please check and help in achieving this. How output should look like, I have already mentioned in question posted above.

Comment: I can only restate @michael-hor257k remark that you say that you are grouping "based on filterValue and format" .. hence your expected result is inconsistent with your grouping description.  I can't help you with an inconsistency in your own logic.